# Facebook SDK 4.x - Display Modal Login on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

Up until this point our iOS app has logged into Facebook via the modal login screen (see image). It appears that Facebook SDK v4.0.1 does not offer this option. Am I correct or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing something ;) I'm working with the new SDK right now too and you have to create an instance of FBSDKLoginManager or FBSDKLoginButton and set it's loginBehavior property to FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb (Web is an WebView).

General information:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3#login-button

For standard login button:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginButton/

If you're using custom control then you need:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/

I think this will help you :)

Comment: I was able to take my existing `FBSDKLoginButton` and use `[self.myFacebookButton setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb]`

Comment: Oh yeah, sure. You can use both of them. I'll add this to my answer.